# Convert JavaScript-generated SVG to a file

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am using d3.js to visualize some data. I would like to be able to take the SVG code that it generates and store it as a `.svg` image file (for editing in Inkscape/Illustrator).

I have tried simply copying the contents of the svg tag i.e.

```
<svg>
<!--snip-->
</svg>
```

into a file called image.svg, but this misses out on the color/styling information, which is in two separate CSS files.

I'm working with [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.html).

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried pasting in the CSS into a `<style>` element?

Comment: yep -- no luck. I'm using Inkscape and Safari to view the resulting .svg. In Inkscape, it shows up as a black blob. In Safari, I get nothing at all.

Comment: @Marcin, a simple example works, but that one seems to fail. Wonder if it is just too much for Inkscape?

Comment: Inkscape is not good for viewing SVG. It is only for composing it. View your SVGs in Chrome.

Comment: @Marcin, I need to share the svg with a designer who will incorporate it into a publication, and I want to make sure they can properly import and manipulate the graphic.

Comment: If your designer is using Inkscape, you're out of luck. If he's using something that can interpret SVG reasonably properly it might work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a nice way to use [svg-crowbar.js](http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/) to provide a button on your site to allow your users to download your visualization as svg.

**1) Define your button's CSS:**

```
.download { 
  background: #333; 
  color: #FFF; 
  font-weight: 900; 
  border: 2px solid #B10000; 
  padding: 4px; 
  margin:4px;
}
```

**2) Define your button's HTML/JS:**

```
<i class="download" href="javascript:(function () { var e = document.createElement('script'); if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') { e.setAttribute('src', 'https://rawgit.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar/gh-pages/svg-crowbar.js'); } else { e.setAttribute('src', 'http://nytimes.github.com/svg-crowbar/svg-crowbar.js'); } e.setAttribute('class', 'svg-crowbar'); document.body.appendChild(e); })();"><!--⤋--><big>⇩</big> Download</i>
```

Here's a closer look at that same javascript:

```
javascript:(function (){ 
    var e = document.createElement('script'); 
    if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') { 
        e.setAttribute('src', 'https://rawgit.com/NYTimes/svg-crowbar/gh-pages/svg-crowbar.js'); 
    } else { 
        e.setAttribute('src', 'http://nytimes.github.com/svg-crowbar/svg-crowbar.js'); 
    } 
    e.setAttribute('class', 'svg-crowbar'); 
    document.body.appendChild(e); 
})();
```

**3) You're done.** This produces an svg download that Inkscape can open.

**Note:** svg-crowbar.js is loaded from https://rawgit.com or http://nytimes.github.com; you may prefer to integrate it into your website/folder.

Answer (score 6):

This is late, but with D3.js it would be simple to inline the CSS. You would do something like:

```
d3.json("../data/us-counties.json", function(json) {
  counties.selectAll("path")
      .data(json.features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", data ? quantize : null)
      .attr("d", path);
});

d3.json("unemployment.json", function(json) {
  data = json;
  counties.selectAll("path")
      .attr("fill", quantize);
});

function quantize(d) {
  return "hsla(120, 50%, 50%, " + Math.min(8, ~~(data[d.id] * 9 / 12)) + ")";
}
```

My function *quantize* is just a quick hack for demonstration, but you could look at [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) to work out the logic for applying quantiles to colors.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in Chrome v16b and Safari v5.1 on Windows: http://phrogz.net/SVG/chloropleth.html

All I did was use the Developer Tools to Copy as HTML the SVG node, paste it into a blank document, and add the links to the two CSS files. Does this appear correctly for you in Safari?

**Edit**: Here it is as a standalone SVG file: http://phrogz.net/SVG/chloropleth.svg
For this I added the `xmlns` attribute to the `<svg>` and the external links:

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet href="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/choropleth.css" type="text/css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/colorbrewer.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- 1MB of data --></svg>
```

*Again, verified to work in Chrome and Safari.*

Comment: when viewed in the browser, it looks great. But when downloaded and loaded into inkscape, it still shows up all black. Do you know what's up with that?

Comment: @JasonSundram I do not; I don't use Inkscape. My guess is that it does not support external CSS references. You could try copy/pasting the contents of those two CSS into a `<style>` block in the SVG and see if it gets better. I can say that Adboe Illustrator also shows it as all black, as it does not support external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension called "[svg-grabber](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-grabber-get-all-the-s/ndakggdliegnegeclmfgodmgemdokdmg)" ([svg export is another option](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/svg-export/naeaaedieihlkmdajjefioajbbdbdjgp/related)) you can try it, it works by just clicking the extension icon, this is the result for stackoverflow page:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is not the answer to the question above, this is just for people who searched how to convert

```
<svg>
...
<svg/>
```

to .svg file.

Just open any .svg file that you dont need with your editor(like VS Code) and replace all of the existing code with your

```
<svg>
...
<svg/>
```

and save it.