# Export an SVG from DOM to file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to create a chart which I want to some how export in vector format to edit in illustrator. Is this possible? This is a snippet of the code that's generated:

[image]

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435537/convert-javascript-generated-svg-to-a-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are more complicated methods involving node.js and server-side rendering but a quick, easy way is to just copy the svg element from the DOM, paste it into a file and save it with the extension .svg

After that you can open it in a vector editor.

Comment: Quick update: Since the method described above will not take an external css file into account I've found that a better method is to use this command line tool for writing html content to a pdf: http://plessl.github.com/wkpdf/

Comment: Update #2: SVG Crowbar is a super handy tool made just for this purpose http://nytimes.github.io/svg-crowbar/

Comment: This method works exceptionally good with svg layers on a leaflet.js map. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [saveSvgAsPng](https://www.npmjs.com/package/save-svg-as-png)

Comment: The OP asked for an export in vector format and your suggested library do the opposite.