# How can we export Kendo Angular2 chart into an image?

Tags: angular, charts, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

I was assuming something like this:

```
<kendo-chart [title]="chartTitle" [series]="chartSeries" export="exportToImage($event)">
          <kendo-chart-series>
            <kendo-chart-series-item [data]="[5, 3, 2, 1]">
            </kendo-chart-series-item>
          </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>

function exportToImage(event){
 //todo code here
}
```

Please share any solution or thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in support using the beta controls for KendoUI Angular2. However, it does generate an SVG HTML element behind the scenes. Your best option is to have an export button and use a third-library that can export a SVG to a file. Have a look at [Convert JavaScript-generated SVG to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435537/convert-javascript-generated-svg-to-a-file)